# How to buy private company stock using a registered account (e.g. LIRA, RRSP)?

Tags: investing, canada, rrsp, private-company

I would like to invest is a private company using money from my LIRA (locked in retirement account).

I know this is allowed, similar to holding private mortgages under these accounts, but how do I actually go about doing this? How do I get the actual money in that account into the hands of the company to buy the stock certificates and hold them designated as if they are under that LIRA?

Comment: I'll write up a more fulsome answer, but in case you are referring to something like what is described here by the CRA, be wary of fraud... https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/news/newsroom/tax-tips/tax-tips-2019/warning-watch-self-directed-rrsp.html

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to hold private company shares within an RRSP, *assuming you are not related to that company per the definition shown here* https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/individuals/topics/rrsps-related-plans/definitions-rrsps.html#prohibited.

[In short, you can't own 10% or more of the company, either directly or indirectly - the most common type of share that might be possible to do this with, then, would be if you had shares through employment of a private company; if it's your own company or similar this won't be possible.]

However, LIRA legislation is actually *pension* legislation [dictated provincially], not *tax* legislation [for the most part dictated federally]. What you can do with LIRA funds is going to depend on the province you are in.